# Swift 4 imagepickerview error

Tags: xcode, swift4

errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Comment: Please add the code that is causing this error. It will be impossible for others to determine how to help you without seeing what you did.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately nobody – I guess – can read your mind. Please add more information.

Comment: Thats the problem i dont know What code that causes the problem it happens in simulator when i pick a picture from library and then the imagepicker dismiss and the picture never appears and i Get this error in the debug console

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the permission to access your library

```
YourPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: YPLAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in()
        if YourPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == YPLAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            // Implement your UIImagepicker method here
        }
    })
```

Comment: OK will this perform a notif when i press the image button ?

Comment: Nope, it will just show you a modal view of your library

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOI5e.png)

this its the code for the image picker